# How to add a Django custom signal to worked out request

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I have a Django project and some foreign API's inside it. So, I have a script, that changes product stocks in my store via marketplace's API. And in my views.py I have a CreateAPIView class, that addresses to marketplace's API method, that allows to get product stocks, and writes it to MYSQL DB. Now I have to add a signal to start CreateAPIView class (to get and add changed stocks data) immediately after marketplace's change stocks method worked out. I know how to add a Django signal with pre_save and post_save, but I don't know how to add a singal on request.

I found some like this:
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(request_finished)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
print("Request finished!")

But it is not that I'm looking for. I need a signal to start an CreateAPIView class after another api class finished its request. I will be very thankfull for any advise how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Custom Signal, which can be called after the marketplace API is hit.

```
custom_signal = Signal(providing_args=["some_data"])
```

Send the signal when marketplace API is hit:

```
def marketplace_api():
    data = 'some_data'
    custom_signal.send(sender=None, some_data=data)
```

Then simply define a receiver function which will contain the logic you need:

```
@receiver(custom_signal)
def run_create_api_view(sender, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs["some_data"]
    if data is not None:
        view = CreateAPIView()
        view.dispatch(data)
```